# Discrete Laplacian with geodesic distances

Tags: differentiation, discrete

Normally, I have a a scalar function *f(x,y)*, sampled on a two dimensional, regularly spaced grid in Cartesian coordinates. Evaluating the Laplacian of this function just requires the standard definition:

\begin{equation}
\Delta f = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}
\end{equation}

and the appropriate discretization of this Laplacian (e.g. *del2* in MATLAB).

Now, however, I want to consider this function defined on a surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. For continuous functions, this would involve the [Laplace-Beltrami operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator) applied to the manifold; the discretization of this, however, seems less well defined. A further complication is that, while the surface in which I am interested is sampled on a triangular mesh, the values of the function on which the Laplacian should be applied are sampled at a subset of points on the mesh. Finally, I have the matrix of geodesic distances between the points of interest.

In this case, does a "standard" discretization of the Laplacian exist? Would this involve re-sampling the triangular mesh in some way, so as to throw out the points which are irrelevant to the calculation?

Any advice on resources or implementation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For 2D coordinates on an arbitrary surface in 3D the Laplacian operator will have to contain metric coefficients corresponding to this surface and your choice of 2D coordinates on the surface. Just look at the Laplace operator in cylindrical and spherical coordinates and you'll see the metric coefficients are there.

Comment: Yes, that's true. However, the question is more focused on the case of discretization over a triangular mesh, and the particular case in which only the geodesic distances between points are known. I hope that's clear in the original question.

Comment: We could discuss approaches to discretization on various grid but this has nothing to do with physics and does not belong to this forum; I recommend moving the question to the computational science stack exchange.

Comment: I had thought of this, but at the same time, I had hoped that there would be more expertise concerning this particular operator here.